# More than one space character between words

Tags: support, formatting

Is it not possible to write more than one space between two words?
Sometimes I need to type more than one space to make my statements look more distinct. However, it automatically turns out to one space anyway.

Comment: Please make sure to test your formatting in several settings; at least test it as "full site" and as "mobile site."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You           can         use HTML entity `&nbsp;` for this purpose. Since it means non-breaking space, it is advisable to separate the instances of `&nbsp;` by ordinary spaces, allowing for a line break.

That said, such formatting should be avoided in all but rare cases. Over-formatting posts rarely benefits them. For example, the line break `<br>` that you used in this question is not necessary and looks unnatural: it should be either a paragraph break (created with a blank line) or no break at all. There's little reason for using line breaks outside of writing poetry.